# Regex - Adapting a VS Code Snippet to convert a label to downcase

Tags: regex, visual-studio-code, vscode-snippets

I am trying to create a snippet for VS Code that creates a label based on the "Section" name:

```json
    "Headings | Section": {
        "prefix": "sec",
        "body": [
            "\\section{${1:section_name}} % (fold)",
            "\t\\label{sec:${2:${1/([^a-zA-Z0-9]+)/_/g}}}",
            "\t$0"
        ],
        "description": "Create a new section with an automatically generated label"
    },
```

All is working fine to remove non alphanumerical characters and replace spaces with underscores, but I am trying (and currently unable) to also make the label lowercase (\downcase). Would be grateful for any assistances.

I have tried implementing variations such as:

```json
"\t\\label{sec:${2:${1/([^a-zA-Z0-9]+)/_/g}${1/(.)/${1:/downcase}/g}}}",
```

For the label and not getting the desired result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this what you are looking for - downcasing the second instance of `$1`:

```
"Headings | Section": {
    "prefix": "sec",
    "body": [
        "\\section{${1:section_name}} % (fold)",
        // "\t\\label{sec:${2:${1/([^a-zA-Z0-9]+)/_/g}}}",
        "\t\\label{sec:${2:${1/([^\\s])|(\\s)/${1:/downcase}${2:+_}/g}}}",
        "\t$0"
    ],
    "description": "Create a new section with an automatically generated label"
},
```

`${1/([^\\s])|(\\s)/${1:/downcase}${2:+_}/g}` this will get all NON-whitespace characters in capture group 1 and all whitespace characters in capture group 2.

All group 1's will be downcased.

If there is a group 2, it will be replaced by an underscore due to `${2:+_}` which is a conditional replacement you can put into snippets which says if group 2 insert an `_`.

---

Use the following form if you want to change something like `HO**WDY* T**HerE **` to `howdy_there`.

```
"\t\\label{sec:${2:${1/(\\w)|(\\s)(?=.*\\w)|[^\\s]|\\s/${1:/downcase}${2:+_}/g}}}",
```

Comment: This works well to make everything lower case, the problem however is that it no longer removes non alphanumeric characters, e.g. "!" wont be removed

Comment: replacing s with W above seems to work though?

Comment: replacing s with W works insofar as replacing non alphanumerical characters with an _, but we actually want to delete these non alphanumerical characters

Comment: Some examples would be helpful.  You want to keep only `[a-zA-Z0-9]`, downcase those, replace spaces with `_` (are 2+ consecutive spaces an issue?) and remove anything else?

Comment: If you want to do what I said in the last comment, try this regex `"\t\\label{sec:${2:${1/(\\w)|(\\s)|\\W/${1:/downcase}${2:+_}/g}}}",`  The only case where that is problematical is if you have a space-separated block of ONLY non- ` \w` characters like ` @@```.  Is that ever the case?  Like `*Howd*y* TH**erE**  ***`.

Comment: I added an option in the answer to change `HO**WDY* T**HerE **` to `howdy_there`.

Comment: Awesome - thanks this is working well.

How could we get the default value for the section label to be defined (e.g. default_label) rather than taking this from the section name ($1)?

Comment: Have created a separate thread for this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76159504/vs-code-regex-in-snippets