# VS Code Regex in Snippets

Tags: regex, visual-studio-code, vscode-snippets

Having some issues with Regex in snippets:

```json
"PT | Headings | Section": {
    "prefix": ["SSE", "sec", "#"],
    "body": [
        "\\section{${1:section_name}} % (fold)",
        "\t\\label{sec:${2:${1/([^\\W])|(\\s+)(?![^a-zA-Z0-9])|(\\W)/${1:/downcase}${2:+_}/g}}}",
        "\t$0"
    ],
    "description": "Create a new section with an automatically generated label"
}
```

Here is an example of a snippet that I have. This works well currently to take the current section name and then insert this into the label (lowercase, with spaces replaced with _ and nonalphanumerical characters removed).

However, I would like to modify this so that the label *doesn't* take the section name and instead we can specify a default value, say "descriptive_label"

Have attempted this and not succeeded, e.g.:
`"\t\\label{sec:${2:${descriptive_label/([^\\W])|(\\s+)(?![^a-zA-Z0-9])|(\\W)/${1:/downcase}${2:+_}/g}}}"`

Expecting to be able to use a specified default instead of $1

Comment: fyi `[^\\W]` is identical to `\\w`

Comment: I think you want to do this: `"\t\\label{sec:${2:descriptive_label}}",`

Comment: @Mark, what about the Regex?

Comment: You want a default value and if you change it to do a regex transform on it?

Comment: Bingo! thats right

Comment: So if I do:

`"\t\\label{sec:${2:descriptive_label${3/([^\\W])|(\\s+)(?![^a-zA-Z0-9])|(\\W)/${1:/downcase}${2:+_}/g}}}"`

It works ALMOST! but the regex isn't then applied to whatever we set the label to be